# Bash printing "\r"

Tags: bash, return, echo

I'm using OS X, and there is no "-e" equivalent.

How can I textually print "\r"?
Is there even a way to do that?

Comment: any other tool? awk, sed, perl, ... ?

Comment: Typing "help echo" on my OSX says is supports neE, where n suppresses newline and e allows interpretation of escaped characters such as \r. What does your "help echo" say?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `echo $'\r'` which is supported by `bash`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
echo "\\r"
```

Works for me.

Comment: Of course! I'm calling that through applescript, so "\\r" was passing "\r" to bash... Using "\\\\r" is good! :) Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't wanna get complicated, since I new I was making a stupid mistake, and that just by seeing the way it's done would help me enough!

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '\r'
```

The `printf` command in general tends to be better than `echo` for cases other than very simple ones.  It has more capabilities and fewer variations from one implementation to another.

Answer (score 1):

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
r=$'\r'
t=$'\t'
echo "${t}${t}1${r}${t}2${r}3"
```

**Output:**

```
3       2       1
```